# Creating copy of jQuery

Tags: jquery

Which is proper way creating a copy from jQuery?

```
var copyjq = new jQuery;
```

`var copyjq` or what?

Comment: i tried but i just want to hear an answer from an expert.

Comment: why down voting? is it now rigth place to ask?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [`sub` method](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.sub/) to create a copy of jQuery:

```
var copyjq= jQuery.sub();
```

Note: For version 1.9 and later the method was moved to a plugin.

If you just want another name for jQuery, and not a separate copy, you can just copy the reference:

```
var copyjq = jQuery;
```

You can also isolate the name inside a function expression:

```
(function(copyjq){
  ...
}(jQuery));
```

Comment: @qqq: Yes. There may be a time limit until you can do that, though.

Comment: yes its saying i need 15 reputation :( how to gain it i dont know i just registered here.